# Testing a Rails helper method that returns HTML, compare with plain text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, helper

I have this Rails helper method that returns text with links inside it:

```rb
def add_to_library_event_text(event)
  user_link = link_to(event.user.username, user_path(event.user))
  game_link = link_to(event.game_purchase.game.name, game_path(event.game_purchase.game))

  return user_link + " added " + game_link + " to their library."
end
```

What I want to do is write a spec for it, to make sure it outputs the right text. I don't care much about the exact details of the HTML, and I'd prefer to do this in a helper spec rather than a feature/browser spec since it's much faster.

I have a working test already, it looks like this:

```rb
expect(helper.add_to_library_event_text(add_to_library_event)).to eq \
  "<a href=\"/users/#{user.username}\">#{user.username}</a> added <a href=\"/games/#{game.id}\">#{game.name}</a> to their library."
```

I'm hoping there's some way that I haven't found yet that will allow me to strip out the HTML from this, so I can write a comparison like this:

```rb
expect(helper.add_to_library_event_text(add_to_library_event)).to eq \
  "#{user.username} added #{game.name} to their library."
```

Is there anything in RSpec/Rails that'd allow me to strip the HTML from this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out how to do this! I use `strip_tags` to strip the HTML from the input string.

```rb
expect(
  strip_tags(helper.add_to_library_event_text(game_purchase_library_event))
).to eq "#{user.username} added #{game.name} to their library."
```

https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html#method-i-strip_tags

You could also use the `sanitize(html_string_goes_here, tags: [])` method, but this is simpler as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

When I want to match particular text within any complex markup (such as HTML), I like to use `match` or `include`, something like this:

```
expect(output).to include "#{user.username} added #{game.name} to their library."
```

or...

```
expect(output).to match /#{user.username} added #{game.name} to their library./
```

This cuts to the essence of what you're testing, and is very resilient to changes in markup, focusing on the content.

Comment: Interesting, I wonder what the performance difference between these two versus strip_tags is.

Comment: Performance is not a great concern here. Either approach is all string manipulation in memory, so it will scroll by faster than you can see. You could run a hundred of these tests in the time of one test with a database write. That said, looking for a substring will be faster than parsing HTML in strip tags.